# How to set the location of a textbox in C# for Windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In Windows FORMS I can set the location by typing:

```
textBox.Location = new point(20,20);
```

But how can I do that in C# for Windows phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows Phone if you want to set location of any UI ELement first you need to set it into Canvas and then you should set its **Top** and **Left** Property

```
 <Canvas Background="LightSteelBlue">
    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="10">Hello World!</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontSize="22" Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="75">Isn't absolute positioning handy?</TextBlock>
  </Canvas>
```

or You can set it into Grid/StackPanel by

```
<object Margin="left,top,right,bottom"/>
<textblock Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! very useful, now got my app running! :D thanks again

Comment: So You Should mark answer as Useful so for future it would useful to others

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone, You can set the **Margin** property for TextBox:

```
textBox.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 0, 0);
```

the 4 params in Thickness are Left, Top, Right, Bottom.